# How to change the type attribute of a script tag in web servers on some conditions

Tags: javascript, regex, apache, webserver

Is there a way to alter the `type` attribute of `script` tags via web server on some circumstances? What I'm looking for could be a web server module (like the Apache `mod_substitute` module) that searches the response body for script tags whose content matches a regular expression and, if found, alters the type attribute of that script tag (from `text/javascript` to `text/plain`).
In other words, a way to block, for example, the execution of the script tag that sets GA on a page w/o need to update the html of that page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: Why not using some PHP to achieve this ? Why do you want to do this in your webserver configuration ?

Comment: Just because I'm looking for a way to block script tags w/o having to edit the page. Consider legacy systems with a lot of pages that are not so easy to edit; having a webserver module (or some sort of) that does the script blocking the way I described above could allow us to avoid edit all the site's pages.

Comment: You mean your server is only serving .html pages ? Then, you could set a php entry point which would modify the html pages before serving them. You wouldn't have to touch to the html pages at all.